# How many permutations of {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I} are there in which the first character is A, B, or C and the last character is G, H, or I?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I understand that it would be n! permutations for the given amount of elements, but I am not sure calculate it with these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the first character.

Choose the last character.

How many ways can you order the remaining $7$?

$3 x 3 x 7!$

Comment: You can obtain $3 \times 3 \times 7!$ by typing `$3 \times 3 \times 7!$` and can obtain $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 7!$ by typing `$3 \cdot 3 \cdot 7!$`.

Answer (score 0):

3 for the first

3 for the last

(n-2)! for the rest.

Multiply them together.

Answer (score 0):

3 options for last place
simultaneously 3 for first place,
now we have 7 objects left. so 7 objects, 7 places 
which is 7!
so answer is 3 *3* 7!